# request.getQueryString not null but request.getParameter(paramname) is null

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, httprequest, getparameter

I have a problem with `request.getParameter(paramname)`. It returns null but when I check StringQuery value, I see  everything  normal.

```
System.out.println("StringQuery= "+getRequest().getQueryString());
```

It writes on console

```
StringQuery= parameter1=2KqEeJtKDG1sQPBUDV%2BhRuLJgdmvb4VCB6pS5q0GDbU%3D&parameter2=ON1yACjEyscSW%2B97O5H9yTnnLa4ui9a%2B
```

After that, I want to get value of `parameter1` with

```
String s = new String(request.getParameter(parameter1));
```

It returns null (s=null)

It happens not all time, randomly it happens.

Any idea,what causes that problem?

Code order

```
System.out.println("StringQuery= "+getRequest().getQueryString());
String s = new String(request.getParameter(parameter1));
```

Comment: You don't need to do `String s = new String(request.getParameter(parameter1));`. You can write it simply as `String s = request.getParameter(parameter1);` unless you want to create a new `String` object. Did you check (print/inspect) the value of `getRequest().getQueryString()`?

Comment: Maybe you should call `request.getParameter("parameter1");`?

Comment: Yes I tried inspect and print,I see querystring has value and its ok.Even to solve problem,I parsed query string  to find params value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
String s = new String(request.getParameter(parameter1));
```

with

```
String s = request.getParameter("parameter1");
```